# Create Custom Place Picker using New Google Place API in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to create custom place picker for Xamari.Android. I could not find the following plugin in xamarin

com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0

Can Anyone help me here? I am trying to implement custom place picker using this link: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/location-places-android/index.html?index=..%2F..index#8

If you guyz have any other way to sort this out do let me know. I want to create a view to pick a location from a map, search location etc.

Currently I have these package installed.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `com.google.android.libraries.places:places` aar library is wrapped via the
`Xamarin.Google.Android.Places` package (the current version is 1.1.0.2)

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.Android.Places/

This Xamarin library source and its sample code are at:

- https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/Android/GooglePlaces

From the sample code:

```
....
if (!PlacesApi.IsInitialized)
   PlacesApi.Initialize (this, apiKey);

placesClient = PlacesApi.CreateClient (this);
placesData = new List<PlaceData> ();
....
```

Comment: Yes I have installed in that plugin, as shown in the picture but still cannot find reference of this class  Places.createClient(this);

Comment: @ZeeshanShakil   I provided the source/example link in my answer (I updated it with a snippet of code from that example)